# data visible in Request Payload section of networking however the data is not available in POST

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to pass json with ajax, the call is goin okay. I can see the data at the Request Payload section but not in post variable.

```
var p = {
            c: c,
            g: g,
            t: t
        };

    var myJSON= JSON.stringify(p);

  $.ajax({
            url: "addedit.php",
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: myJSON,
            success: function () {
                alert("success");
            }
        });
```

**PHP code :**

```
$myjson= array();

$myjson= json_decode($_POST['myJSON']);

var_dump($myjson);die;
```

[image: networking section]

[image: POST data]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Receive JSON POST with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866571/receive-json-post-with-php)

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass the data as the object

```
data: {
    myJSON:              myJSON
},
```

Full `ajax` request

```
$.ajax({
    url: "addedit.php",
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        myJSON:              myJSON
    },
    success: function () {
        alert("success");
    }
});
```

My Input data

```
var p = {
        c: 1001,
        g: 4,
        t: 100
    };
```

In your `php` file just do this

```
$myjson= json_decode($_POST['myJSON'],true);
var_dump($myjson);
```

The output of `var_dump` below

```
array(3) { ["c"]=> int(1001) ["g"]=> int(4) ["t"]=> int(100) }
```

Comment: thanks for the help, but i have already tried this, yet the same result like "Notice: Undefined index: myJSON in C:\xampp\htdocs\fne\addedit.php on line 8
NULL" and also the alert "success" is also not firing up

Comment: @John, I have updated my answer. Please check now. It's working fine for my local

Comment: same result as earlier "Notice: Undefined index: myJSON in C:\xampp\htdocs\fne\addedit.php on line 10
NULL

Comment: perhaps i must clear this, the variable c,g,t are the values from the table that i'm trying to pass as json

Comment: @John, I pass your data like your input and share the output edited answer

Comment: i change data to var p = { c: 1001, g: 4, t: 100 }; still it shows NULL in output

Comment: @John, Please careful `ajax` code. No need two lines of code `dataType: 'json',
contentType: 'application/json',`